# Is it rollback-safe to upgrade MongoDB from 2.0.2 to 2.2?

Tags: mongodb

I want to upgrade MongoDB from 2.0.2 to latest version, but I am a bit worried about just running mongod with the current data-files.

In case something goes wrong will I be able to just stop mongod and run the old setup (v. 2.0.2)? Or, in other words, does new mongod apply any changes to the data files that makes them unusable with mongod 2.0.2?

Comment: It should not apply any new changes to the data files, it should be able to produce a drop in replacement however if you are using replica sets a good method might be to take one member out, start that as a stand alone and test the new mongodb version there.

Comment: No, we don't use replica sets. I know it should not apply any new changes, I just want to find some proof of that idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted on the upgrade page: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.2/

> MongoDB 2.0 data files are compatible with 2.2-series binaries without any special migration process.

So yes there should be no changes to the files. The last time changes were needed (a new version of indexes was implemented) the upgrade page did mention additional information regarding the migration process.

Also taking a look at the changes section: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.2/#changes there does not appear to be any file format changes. There have been a few behavioural changes ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.2/#behavioral-changes ) however this should only effect future work on your files (i.e. changes in restrictions on names).

I would bet a fair amount it would be safe to just drop the 2.2 binary in place of 2.0.

I recently upgraded from 1.9 without any problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've read the release notes, but was looking for more evidence or someone's experience in upgrading.

Comment: @RakhimDavletkaliyev if your really paranoid, what I did was backup my files to S3 first and then did the upgrade cos I upgraded from 1.9 to 2.4 so I was a bit anxious